# Valgrind `Unsupported arch_prctl option`

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I have a program that I know has some weird memory issues going on, so I turned to Valgrind. However, I am getting the following mysterious output:

```
==32006== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==32006== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==32006== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==32006== Command: ./012
==32006== Parent PID: 29454
==32006== 

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Unsupported arch_prctl option

host stacktrace:
==32006==    at 0x580441BA: show_sched_status_wrk (m_libcassert.c:355)
==32006==    by 0x580442D4: report_and_quit (m_libcassert.c:426)
==32006==    by 0x58044517: panic (m_libcassert.c:502)
==32006==    by 0x58044517: vgPlain_core_panic_at (m_libcassert.c:507)
==32006==    by 0x5804454A: vgPlain_core_panic (m_libcassert.c:512)
==32006==    by 0x580DAE22: vgSysWrap_amd64_linux_sys_arch_prctl_before (syswrap-amd64-linux.c:286)
==32006==    by 0x580A0C23: vgPlain_client_syscall (syswrap-main.c:1857)
==32006==    by 0x5809D48A: handle_syscall (scheduler.c:1126)
==32006==    by 0x5809EBB6: vgPlain_scheduler (scheduler.c:1443)
==32006==    by 0x580AED50: thread_wrapper (syswrap-linux.c:103)
==32006==    by 0x580AED50: run_a_thread_NORETURN (syswrap-linux.c:156)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 32006)
==32006==    at 0x401A1C5: ??? (in /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so)
==32006==    by 0xBFEBFBFE: ???


Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution.
It contains workarounds to several common problems.
In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after
identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance
that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or
crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.

If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org

In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind
version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.
```

The original bug I am trying to diagnose occurs when I am trying to insert `uint64_t`s into a `std::set` based on values in a `std::vector` (not a pointer in sight).

Comment: If you google for "valgrind arch_prctl unsupport option" or the like, you'll see the bug reports about it. Sounds like your kernel's too old to run that release of valgrind. I don't know if there's an official valgrind update with fix that's been released yet.

Comment: [Archlinux Bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/59551), [Upstream KDE Bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=396887)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `valgrind-git` package from AUR and it may work